# Running Wget in scala build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a requirement where I need to download a bunch of jars from a url and then place them inside a lib directory and then add them to unmanaged dependancy.

I am kind of stuck on how to do this in `build.sbt`. Went over sbt documentation and I found processbuilder. With that in mind, I came up with the below code.

```
for(i <- jarUrls) {
  val wget = s"wget -P $libDir $anonUser@$hgRootURL/$i"
  wget !
}
```

This runs `wget` on a bunch of jars and then places the file in the mentioned folder. Pretty simple code, but I am unable to run this. The error that I get is "Expression of type `Unit` must confirm to `DslEntry` in SBT file".

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.sbt` isn't just `scala` file, sbt does special preprocessing on it (that's why you don't have to `def project =` etc).

Your problem happens because every line of code (except imports and definitions) in build.sbt must return expression of type `DslEntry` as sbt sees every line of code as setting. When do you want your wget to get executed? usual way is to define `Task`:

```
lazy val wget = taskKey[Unit]("Wget")

wget := {
  for(i <- List(1,2,3)) {
    val wget = s"wget -P $libDir $anonUser@$hgRootURL/$i"
    wget !
  }
  ()
}
```

and run it like `sbt wget`.

You can also make `wget` task dependent on some other task (or you can think of them as events) in sbt.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html

Of course, there are tricky unsafe ways, like:

```
val init: Unit = {
   //any code you want here
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend it since you probably want those files during let's say `compile` stage or something:

```
wget := {
  your code here
} dependsOn compile
```

you can also use regular scala build instead of `build.sbt`: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Full-Def.html

Comment: Where should I place this code snippet? Inside build.sbt itself ?  because it results in the same error I mentioned above. I want it run each time sbt itself invoked since it adds all jars to classpath

Comment: @GreedyCoder Are you sure you need to download it every time you run sbt? Anyways, see my update

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it and I considered this as a separate task and not run each time :)